# Rails rollback transaction when saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I  keep running into a "rollback transaction" error just after the pry in my Lists_Controllers when I try to save @list

I am using nested forms, and when I pry into the @list.invites, it shows that invite.id is nil (but the email is there).  I'm wondering if this is the cause.

```
[3] pry(#<ListsController>)> @list.invites
=> [#<Invite:0x007f91de392e30
  id: nil,
  accepted: nil,
  exp_date: nil,
  email: "sldkfjsdf@email.com",
  invite_code: nil,
  list_id: nil,
  user_id: nil,
  created_at: nil,
  updated_at: nil>]
```

Here's my Lists Controller

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @list = List.new
    @list.invites.build
  end


  def create
    @list  = List.create(list_params)
    @list.users << current_user
    @list.admin_id = current_user.id
    binding.pry
    if @list.save
      redirect_to @list
    else
     render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def list_params
    params.require(:list).permit(:name, invites_attributes: [:email])
  end
 end
```

And here's my List.rb

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
has_many :lists_users
has_many :users, through: :lists_users
has_many :chores
has_many :invites

accepts_nested_attributes_for :invites , reject_if: proc { |attributes| 
attributes['email'].blank? }

validates :name, presence: true

end
```

And my Invites.rb

```
class Invite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And my Lists and Invites Table Schemas

```
create_table "invites", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean "accepted"
    t.datetime "exp_date"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "invite_code"
    t.integer "list_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "lists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "list_type"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "admin_id"
  end
```

And my form

```
<%= form_for(@list) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %><br>
      Invites:
      <%= f.fields_for :invites do |invite| %>
        <%= invite.label :email %>
        <%= invite.text_field :email %>
      <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

And here's the error when I try @list.save in pry

```
pry(#<ListsController>)> @list.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: Can you show your Invites model? This looks like you may need to set the `inverse_of` option on your relationship. This can happen because as all these models are trying to save, since they don't know about each other being created they are failing validations. `inverse_of` lets Rails know about the relationship and lets the transactions save.

Comment: I just updated the question with the Invites model.  I'll look into the inverse_of option right now.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured out the problem.  When I removed the has_many and belong_to relationship between User and Invite, it worked.  Trying to figure out now how to preserve that relationship as I need Users.invites to determine who has been invited

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my has_many and belongs_to relationship between the User and Invite.  When an invite is sent, if an email exists in the system, the user who owns the email is assigned the invite.  At List creation, if the invite email doesn't belong to someone with an account, then there is no user_id to assign to the new invite.  I'll have to figure out how I'm going to accomplish this, but the original error is fixed.